# process out of memory on big file load to mongo in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parsing, csv, large-files

I'm trying to save and parse large .csv files and save the data in MongoDB, keeping the results in string type. So I'm trying to pipe the .csv file data, through a parser and then write the data to MongoDB.

I tried parsing the .csv to a json file and using `mongoimport` to upload it to MongoDB, which worked fine, but the values weren't kept as strings and you cant set values when using `mongoimport`.

I also don't want to set the memory for node and try and use as little memory as possible.

My problem at the moment is: the program runs out of memory and throws:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('csv-parse');
var async = require('async');

var queue, stream;
var headers = fileData.subText.meta.fields;


MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection(fileData.collectionName);
    var parser = parse({columns: fileData.subText.meta.fields, delimiter: fileData.delimiter});
    stream = fs.createReadStream("filepath" + fileData.name).pipe(parser);
    var data;

    queue = async.queue(function (task, next) {
         data = task.data;
         collection.insert(data, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                db.close();
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    }, 50);

    stream.on('data', function (data) {
        stream.pause();
        queue.push({
            data: data
        });
    });

    queue.drain = function () {
        stream.resume();
    };

    stream.on('end', function () {
        return queue.drain = function () {
            db.close();
            return console.log('Process Done');
        };
    });
});
```

I got the idea from this link: https://bassnutz.wordpress.com/2012/09/09/processing-large-files-with-nodejs/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its says that RAM does not have enough space to allocate the process. it should have enough RAM space to load the process.

Comment: I ran it without this part

collection.insert(data, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                db.close();
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });

and it doesnt complain about memory.

Comment: Actually when you ru  the insert query then mongod will require the more memory to perform the insert operation then it happens......To check the memory issue in linux. type top command and watch.